# sort a pandas df based on column values that has mix of integer and list of two integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a dataframe:
temp_df

```
line  sheet  comments
1     apple  this is a fruit
2     orange this is fruit
[1,3] onion  this is a vegetable
```

I want to sort this temp_df dataframe based on sheet and line but since line has mix of integer and list. I will take the first index if the column value is a list.
so the sorted temp_df looks like:

```
line  sheet  comments
    1     apple  this is a fruit
    [1,3] onion  this is a vegetable
    2     orange this is fruit
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

# data setup
data = [[1, 2, [1, 3]], ["apple", "onion", "orange"],
        ["this is a fruit", "this is a vegetable", "this is a fruit"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(*data), columns=["line", "sheet", "comments"])

result = df.assign(key=[s if isinstance(s, list) else [s] for s in df["line"]]) \
    .sort_values("key").drop("key", axis=1)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
     line   sheet             comments
0       1   apple      this is a fruit
2  [1, 3]  orange      this is a fruit
1       2   onion  this is a vegetable
```

In `pandas >= 1.1`, you could use the key parameter of `sort_values` see [sorting with keys](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#sorting-with-keys). Like follows:

```
result = df.sort_values(by=['line'], key=lambda ix: [s if isinstance(s, list) else [s] for s in ix])
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! let me try this implementation.

Comment: Nice one!  @Dani Mesejo do you know why this solution doesn't work?
`df.sort_values('a', key=lambda x: x[0] if type(x) is list else x)`  it gives `TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'`

Comment: @IoaTzimas The second solution is for pandas >= 1.1. In particular I tested it in 1.1.4